# Change Cursor when combobox dropdown is open

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to change the cursor to "Hand" when dropdown of a combobox is open.
So I did the below on `comboBox1_DropDownOpened` event. But the problem is cursor changes. But when I move through the menu Items the Cursor is remaining  as a Arrow.

Please advice me.

```
private void comboBox1_DropDownOpened(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    this.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;    
}
```

Comment: I think I heard something about some versions of Windows not supporting the Hand cursor. Could that be it? If I recall correctly, WPF doesn't list Hand among the other cursors as well.

Comment: @chris- Cursor is changing. If I move cursor out from the Combobox, I can see it. Problem is when I point to menu item of combobox, it shows like an arrow.

Comment: Ah, I was just experimenting and I got it to show the hand on buttons by looping through the items and changing each's cursor, but the part, say, beside the button in an item wouldn't.

Comment: I solved the issue. Thank you for your quick response. I have posted the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great. I was able to solve my problem by making the cursor of menu item to hand. :)

```
ComboBoxItem ci=new ComboBoxItem();
ci.Cursor=Cursors.Hand;
```

This works fine. Thank you everyone.

Comment: It works, but I'm left wondering if there's a way to change it for items such as buttons that you add to it. For a button, only the button's cursor changes if you loop through the combo box's items. The rest of that space in the spot of the menu is left untouched.